# Parquet backed table corrupted - HIVE - expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [1, 92, 78, 10]

Tags: hive, hdfs, parquet

Distribution: CDH-4.6.0-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.26
Hive Version: 0.10.0
Parquet Version: 1.2.5

I have two big date partitioned external Hive tables full of log files that I recently converted to Parquet to take advantage of the compression and columnar storage.  So far I've been very happy with the performance.

Our dev team recently added a field to the logs, so I was charged with adding a column to both log tables.  It worked perfectly for one, but the other appears to have become corrupted.  I reverted the change, but I still can't query the table.

I'm convinced the data is fine (because it didn't change) but something is wrong in the metastore.  An msck repair table repopulates the partitions after I drop/create, but does not take care of the error below.  There are two things that can fix it, but neither are making me happy:

1. Re-insert the data.
2. Copy data back into the table from the production cluster.

I'm really hoping there's a command that I don't know about that will fix the table without needing to resort to the above 2 options.  Like I said, the data is fine.  I've googled the heck out of the error, and I get some results but they all pertain to Impala which is NOT what were using.

```
select * from upload_metrics_hist where dt = '2014-07-01' limit 5;
```

The problem is this:

**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: hdfs://hdfs-dev/data/prod/upload-metrics/upload_metrics_hist/dt=2014-07-01/000005_0 is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [1, 92, 78, 10]**

Full error

```
2014-07-17 02:00:48,835 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:372)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(HadoopShimsSecure.java:319)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:433)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:540)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:394)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:358)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: hdfs://hdfs-dev/data/prod/upload-metrics/upload_metrics_hist/dt=2014-07-01/000005_0 is not a Parquet file. expected magic number at tail [80, 65, 82, 49] but found [1, 92, 78, 10]
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:263)
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:229)
at parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat$RecordReaderWrapper.getSplit(DeprecatedParquetInputFormat.java:327)
at parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat$RecordReaderWrapper.<init>(DeprecatedParquetInputFormat.java:204)
at parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat.getRecordReader(DeprecatedParquetInputFormat.java:108)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:65)
... 15 more
```

Comment: Could you please share the hive command which you used for converting the table file format as parquet. Usually the above mentioned error will occur only if the file in which the table pointing is not a parquet file. Parquet file should be in ".parquet" format. Also the parquet file will contain a header as 'PAR1'. In your case while selecting the data , hive internally check if the file contain a header as 'PAR1' . Since it is not a parquet format , it will throw an error like magic number.

Comment: Meta information got corrupt . refresh command  to fix.